# Powershell Excel PivotFilters.Add

Tags: excel, powershell, pivot-table

I've written a Powershell script to grab a CSV, create an Excel sheet from it, and create a Pivottable with a few rows and summary values.  I'm also able to add a filter field but what I cannot successfully do is tell the filter field what value I want it to filter on.

The PivotFilters.Add and PivotFilters.Add2 methods always throw a "Value does not fall within the expected range" error.

Here's the relevant portions of the code:

```
# Add PivotTable
$WS2 = $WBK1.Worksheets.Add()   
$WS2.Name = "PivotTable"

$xlPivotTableVersion15     = 5 # Excel 2013
$xlPivotTableVersion12     = 3 # Excel 2007
$xlDescending              = 2
$xlDatabase                = 1 # this just means local sheet data
$xlHidden                  = 0
$xlRowField                = 1
$xlColumnField             = 2
$xlFilterField             = 3
$xlDataField               = 4    
$xlSum                     = -4157
$xlAverage                 = -4106
$xlCount                   = -4112
$xlRight                   = -4152

$pivotRange = $WS1.UsedRange    

$PivotTable = $WBK1.PivotCaches().Create($xlDatabase,$pivotRange,$xlPivotTableVersion15)
$PivotTable.CreatePivotTable("R1C1","Tables1") | Out-Null 
[void]$WS2.Select()

$WBK1.ShowPivotTableFieldList = $true 

# configure pivottable fields

$PivotFields = $WS2.PivotTables("Tables1").PivotFields("VmName")
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlRowField

$PivotFields = $WS2.PivotTables("Tables1").PivotFields("RAM")
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlDataField
$PivotFields.Function = $xlAverage

$PivotFields = $WS2.PivotTables("Tables1").PivotFields("vCPU")
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlDataField
$PivotFields.Function = $xlAverage

$PivotFields = $WS2.PivotTables("Tables1").PivotFields("Dept") # I also tried commenting these lines out
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlFilterField                      # I also tried commenting these lines out

$xlValueEquals = 7
$xlCaptionEquals = 15
$WS2.PivotTables("Tables1").PivotFields("Dept").PivotFilters.Add2($xlValueEquals, "Finance")
```

I have tried using both PivotFilters.Add and PivotFilters.Add2 either way I always get "Value does not fall within the expected range."

I've also tried commenting out the lines annotated above as I wondered if already having a filter created was confusing it.

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

OK so in the end I found that basically writing a value into the cell of the filter I created using...

```
$PivotFields = $WS2.PivotTables("Tables1").PivotFields("Dept")
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlFilterField
```

...worked and so I could do away with the PivotFilters.Add / PivotFilters.Add2 method.  If anyone does know the answer to that I'm sure someone on t'interweb would be grateful for the solution being shared.

Answer (score 0):

I too never got the `PivotFilters.Add` method to work. What did work for me, however, was creating and manipulating a slicer.

Once created and configured (e.g. a date slicer), you can query the slicer's `SlicerCacheLevel.SlicerItems` array for valid values and then apply filtering / slice the data by updating the array in `SlicerCache.VisibleSlicerItemsList`.

Confusingly, there is a `SlicerCacheLevel.VisibleSlicerItemsList` that errors when you try to update it. I didn't look into further as `SlicerCache.VisibleSlicerItemsList` worked.